# getting data from four tables with tight WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need help getting data from different tables and insert into other different table Here are the Queries

```
"SELECT commentID, date, comment, subject, parentID, aBUserID FROM comments WHERE status = 'APPROVED'"

"SELECT topicID, subForumID, aBUserID, lastPostID, views, replies, startDate FROM topic WHERE status = 'APPROVED' AND topicID = $parentid";
 // $parentID need to be matched from above query parentID,

"SELECT userName FROM users WHERE aBUserID = $cmtaBUserID";
// $cmtaBUserID = aBUserID from first query

"SELECT userName FROM users WHERE aBUserID = $topicaBUserID";
//$topicaBUserID = aBUserID from second query
```

Last 2 queries are from same table but using different where clause
i used different inner join left join from solutions posted here but non of these worked for me stuck since last 2 weeks please help

PS data from all above Queries will be inserted to a single table i need these to be combined so i can have them all in one place

Comment: What do you need help with? Connecting to the database? Getting the right data? Iterating through the result set? What does your database look like? Where is your PHP code?

Comment: Thanks i need to combined these queries using join as $conditions from above queries are not returning any data and query fails

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the operation in same query use 'OR'

"SELECT userName FROM users WHERE aBUserID = $cmtaBUserID OR aBUserID = $topicaBUserID";

Comment: As well as `OR`, you could also use an `IN`, which I find a little easier to read.

Comment: NO returned data from both queries will be treated for different fields of table to insert so cant use OR

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

SELECT `userName`  from `users` where `aBUserID` IN(SELECT `aBUserID` FROM comments WHERE status = 'APPROVED')

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't test it but Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT c.commentID, c.date, c.comment, c.subject, c.parentID, c.aBUserID, 
       t.topicID, t.subForumID, t.aBUserID, t.lastPostID, t.views, t.replies, t.startDate,
       u.userName
FROM 
       comments c 
       left outer join topic t on t.topicID = c.parentID
       left outer join users u on u.aBUserID = c.aBUserID and u.aBUserID = t.aBUserID
WHERE
       c.status = 'APPROVED' and t.status = 'APPROVED';
```

Comment: Yes This is what i was looking for Thank you very much a little more help on <code>left outer join users u on u.aBUserID = c.aBUserID and u.aBUserID = t.aBUserID</code> will i be able to separate username from topic table and username from comment

Comment: 'able to separate'? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
    comment.[commentID],
    comment.[date],
    comment.[comment],
    comment.[subject],
    comment.[parentID],
    comment.[aBUserID], 
    commentuser.[userName],
    topic.[topicID],
    topic.[subForumID],
    topic.[aBUserID],
    topic.[lastPostID],
    topic.[views],
    topic.[replies],
    topic.[startDate],
    topic.[userName]
FROM comments comment
LEFT OUTER JOIN users commentuser
    ON commentuser.aBUserID = comment.[aBUserID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        t.[topicID],
        t.[subForumID],
        t.[aBUserID],
        t.[lastPostID],
        t.[views],
        t.[replies],
        t.[startDate],
        u2.[userName] --user from users table joined to topics table
    FROM topic t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users u
        ON u.aBUserID = t.[aBUserID]
    WHERE t.[status] = 'APPROVED'
) topic
    ON topic.topicID = comment.parentID
WHERE comment.[status] = 'APPROVED'
```